# Verify server host key with psftp in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, sftp, putty

I am getting below message while running my SFTP command batch file through Windows Service.

> The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
>   have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
>   think it is.
>   The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
>   ssh-rsa 1024 cc:78:13:a3:68:a6:59:7e:b8:23:2d:13:3e:66:9b:b9
>   If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
>   PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
>   If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
>   adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
>   If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
>   connection.
>   Store key in cache? (y/n)
>   Connection abandoned.

SSH keys are already cached in the below path,

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys
```

But since my Windows Service is running on Local Machine, i need to copy the same Keys in the below path manually,

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostkeys
```

Is there any other way to do this automatically when the service starts for the first time?

or

Is there any command to copy the cache from one registry to another (i.e) from "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys" to "HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software\"

I used below command,

```
Copy-Item -Path 'HKCU:\Software\SimonTatham\' -Destination 'hku:\Software\' -Recurse
```

but got error, not valid file path

Answer (score 2):

The host key should ideally be a part of your script package (it's part of the session information, along with a host name, an user name, etc.).

Recent versions of the `psftp` do allow specifying the expected hostkey using the `-hostkey` switch:

```
psftp.exe user@example.com -hostkey aa:bb:cc:...
```

---

My previous answer from times the `psftp.exe` did not have the `-hostkey` switch:

You have to export the `SshHostkeys` registry key to a file and import it from the script (batch file) before you run SFTP.

Or use another scriptable SFTP client that allows specifying the host key in a script. E.g. with WinSCP you can do:

```
open sftp://martin:mypassword@example.com/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx...="
```

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*